# Firefox: How to allow remembering of media query setting on non secure page?

Tags: firefox, security

The image below says almost everything, but I'm adding this text so it is easier to search for.  “Remember this decision” does not work.

The response is “Your connection to this site is not secure…”

[image: Your connection to this site is not secure.]

Is there a way I can disable this?  I'm trying to do some development on a personal server, and it's a huge hassle having to verify over and over again that I want to use my microphone.  Something in about:config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable this protection without changing Firefox's code.
Code controlling this protection:

```
// Disable the permanent 'Allow' action if the connection isn't secure, or for
// screen/audio sharing (because we can't guess which window the user wants to
// share without prompting).
let reasonForNoPermanentAllow = "";
if (sharingScreen) {
  reasonForNoPermanentAllow = "getUserMedia.reasonForNoPermanentAllow.screen3";
} else if (sharingAudio) {
  reasonForNoPermanentAllow = "getUserMedia.reasonForNoPermanentAllow.audio";
} else if (!aRequest.secure) {
  reasonForNoPermanentAllow = "getUserMedia.reasonForNoPermanentAllow.insecure";
}
```

[Link to source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/modules/webrtcUI.jsm#776)

Comment: Darn.  Thank you for the info.  It's amazing that you knew exactly the lines of code for this, and I'm glad you shared them.